# LSP with C++ Project built in Docker

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I have a C++ project built in a docker instance with its own set of libraries, toolchains, etc, and I'm trying to use LSP with spacemacs on the host machine outside docker. There is a `compile_commands.json` as a softlink in the project root.
I'm having issues using both `lsp-clangd` and `lsp-ccls` as backends to my `c-c++` layer.
I think I have more success with `lsp-ccls` but it also reporting errors like "'memory' file not found" for a line saying

`#include <memory>`

I don't see any noticeable errors in `*ccls::stderr*`.

Comment: the paths _inside_ your softlinked `compile_commands.json` have to match what your editor can see, or else things wont work.